# Get method without the?

Tags: php, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL rewriting - Beginners guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707129/url-rewriting-beginners-guide)

Hey Guys I've been seeing sites using what I think is php's get method but i dont see the url like: http://myfakeurl.com/?id=8

I instead see it like this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYuOe.jpg

Is that the get method they are using? How do you do that if it is?

Thanks!

Comment: Search [`mod_rewrite`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is called "url rewriting" - there are different approaches to do this, for example using [apaches mod_rewrite](http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/).