# How to accept GET arguments through a URL, but without having ".php?argument=value"

Tags: php, javascript, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to: URL re-writing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-url-re-writing-in-php)

How can a website use an argument that you provide directly in the URL?

For example, you can visit:

http://isup.me/www.google.com

And then the scripts on that site can use the value www.google.com to see if the site is up.

I could do this with:

http://isup.me/index.php?url=ww.google.com

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

But that isn't very clean, and I would love to know how it is done the other way.

Thanks a lot!
pimvdb pointed out that this was a duplicate of this question:

[How to do URL re-writing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-url-re-writing-in-php)

Comment: Some frameworks provide more direct ways of doing it, but really what you've got there is pretty much the answer.  You could maybe come up with a mini-framework of your own to split up the URL according to some consistent pattern, or whatever.

Comment: use mod_rewrute in apache, or it equivalent in whatever httpd you're using.  The data is still in $_GET but its format is hidden by the URL rewriting.  That's how it's usually done.

Comment: How would you make a form send users to a modified URL like that? Does it just always involve either Javascript or a redirect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need *ModRewrite*.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your server config.

Everytime I've done this, I've used [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for apache: *(.htaccess file)*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#If not an existing File
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#AND If not an existing Directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#rewrite to test.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) /test.php?site=$1 [L]
```

You can test this out using the php file:

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mod_rewrite for that!

Example of a .htaccess File's content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?get_var_name=$1
```