# Apache friendly urls. How to?

Tags: php, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to: URL re-writing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-url-re-writing-in-php)

There are many examples of my question online but since it involves some RegEx I could use a little help from you.

How can I convert this URL....

```
www.example.com/profile.php?user=username123
```

...into this URL?

```
www.example.com/username123
```

Comment: In that form, this question has been asked and answered already. Unless you do not show what you've tried so far and explained per given examples what did not work in *your* case because of what it is different, I do not have much motivation to help. Just saying.

Comment: Alright. I'll make it sound way more complicated than it is while at the same time coming to the same conclusion which is. I do not understand MOD REWRITE or REGEX. I'll be back to copy and paste some examples I've found which will give the illusion of research while I remain clueless as to how it works.

Comment: It's just that to understand regex, you need to learn. Start with something simple. Regular expressions are a sort of language on it's own with their own rules. When I started with mod_rewrite years back, I normally used the (that time apache 1.x) documentation. They have a list of examples what you can do with mod_rewrite and how.

Comment: Sarcasm is the lowest form of wit. Instead, why not put your efforts into helping the people trying to help you, or doing (trivial) research?

Comment: It seems easier to understand women than regex.

Comment: Oh gosh. You are so male or what? Sorry, but this is getting out of hands.

Comment: "Regular expressions are a sort of language on it's own with their own rules." Come on, what else fits this description to a T? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called .htaccess in your root folder and write the following in it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: if my root folder already contains one, can i place this code anywhere in it or somewhere specifically?

Comment: Do you mean in your root you have already an .htaccess file?

Comment: yeah it's in my root. it has so default mod rewrite roles but not like yours.

Comment: Well add `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]` after the last line and see what happens

Comment: It did not. when I type www.mysite.com/vini it does not retrieve the contents of www.mysite.com/profile.php?user=vini I get a 404 page not found isntead.

Comment: Then try deleting everything that was in your .htaccess file and replace it all with my previous code.

Comment: Internal server error when I do that.

Comment: well I am using the same code to redirect a user from `site.com/index.php` to display `site.com\user` in the middle there is a `profile.php?user=user` the problem could be from your apache. If you want to learn about url-rewrite thought, this is s great tutorial: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/?searched=url&advsearch=oneword&highlight=ajaxSearch_highlight+ajaxSearch_highlight1

Comment: i'm using the htaccess file that came with http://html5boilerplate.com/ also using WAMP.

Comment: Well my site is costume built, and it is easier that way to debug.