# Rewrite URL of custom php based E-Commerce Website

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have experimented a lot already however they did not work for me, so i have to put this query for which i need very specific solutions.

No CMS is used. The website is an eCommerce site developed using php

My site url structure is

- For Product Pages =  `https://www[dot]sitename.com/product.php?product=productid`
- For Category Pages =  `https://www[dot]sitename.com/category.php?category=category-name`
- For SubCat Pages = `https://www[dot]sitename.com/category.php?subcategory=sub-category-name`

I want

- For Product Pages =  `https://www[dot]sitename.com/product/productid/`
- For Category Pages=  `https://www[dot]sitename.com/category/category-name`
- For SubCat Pages = `https://www[dot]sitename.com/category/subcategory/sub-category-name`

How can i do this using .htaccess?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-url-re-writing-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Products    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?product=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

# Categories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?category=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

# Sub-categories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^category/subcategory/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?subcategory=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following htaccess rules work for me, and hopefully these will work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule    ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    category.php?category=$1   [NC,L]    # Handle category

RewriteRule    ^category/subcategory/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    category.php?subcategory=$1   [NC,L]    # Handle sub category

RewriteRule    ^product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    product.php?product=$1   [NC,L]    # Handle product
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions. However none of the methods worked for me. Let me add few more things about the site and hosting which may help you analyze my problem and provide alternative solutions.

1. The website is hosted on Godaddy Shared Hosting
2. The website is not using any CMS