# How can I change the URL of a php page with apache

Tags: php, apache

I want for example make this:

Original URL: `domain.com/folder/index.php?i=something`

Changed URL: `domain.com/folder/something`

But keeping the content of the original URL, with the RewriteRule of apache. And can someone tell me of a good tutorial or a documentation of how to use that?

Comment: You should go see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-url-re-writing-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Open  httph.conf  fine :  #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so, then uncheck #
(LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so)
Create .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folder/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+).html$ index.php?id=$2

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1
```

you config error 
ErrorDocument Error_code /error.html
Example: ErrorDocument 404/error_404.html

Answer (score -1):

```
# Open The RewriteEngine 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# Rewrite 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^bbs/test-([0-9]+)\.html$ bbs/test.php?id=$1&%1

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^jingdian-([0-9]+)\.html$ jingdian.php?id=$1&%1
```

Comment: Your answer is completely wrong