# getting stuck for change files url in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new in .htaccess file, so I want to change my every file different URL 1st default I use this its work for only 1 file

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ xrl.php?xrl=$1
> ```

Then I change my contactus.php file URL then I do this from Google  below

> ```
> RewriteRule ^Contact-us$ contact.php [L]
> ```

Its not work some method more I try but whole website not work. How I change my every file different URL  as I want.

Comment: you want to remove .php extension from page name?

Comment: @Zeeshan yeh remove .php but specific files. aboutus.php and contactus.php also i want to change url Like contactus.php as Contact-Us  and aboutus.php as About-us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can rewrite urls using .htaccess files. But before writing something in .htaccess files we need to verify which kind of server we are using. Here in the case you may use either an apache server or a Nginx server. You can easily check by just adding a

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

in a php page.

**Case 1 : Apache Server:**

Ensure that mod_rewrite module enabled in apache server. This can be identified by checking phpinfo included page.

Common methods used for url rewriting is as follows

**RewriteEngine**

This is mandatory for any apache server. This is used to enable the rewriting engine. In some cases it should be on by default.So ensure that following code must be mandatory in top of your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
```

RewriteRule

in some cases you may have only few pages and you can specify each page in your website in .htaccess file. In such case you can use these kind of rewriting 
For example

RewriteRule ^article/used/to/be/here.php$ /article/now/lives/here/ [R=301,L]

Suppose you have to rewrite url like these

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/url_rewriting
```

You should write something like these on your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^wiki/(.+)$   w/index.php?title=$1   [L]
```

But actual implementation of the page will be like these

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=url_rewriting

**RewriteCond**

This can be used for rewriting certain url with respect to some conditions. Suppose you need to add or remove www with your website name and on certain condition redirect to certain page like "url not available or error message "

Example :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
```

You can further refer here

[Introduction to url rewriting](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)

[Rewrite with examples](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples-2/)

**Case 2 : nginx Server**

Enable module HttpRewriteModule on your nginx server
Use location to rewrite you urls as per nginx settings

Example

```
    location / {
    root   /path/to/drupal;
    index  index.php index.html;
 
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
 
location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for hiding .php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Reference Links

[Link 1](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/02/hide-php-url-rewriting-htaccess.html)

[Link 2](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-url-re-writing-in-php)

Comment: no work :' ( when i use ur 1st code its make error not found. in every page. and second code not work.

Comment: @user3458209 check Ref links