# Correct syntax for mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

What is the correct syntax to use in an Apache 2.4.7 `.htaccess` file to get

`http://www.example.com/go/stuff`

to rewrite to:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?tab=go&page=stuff`?

What syntax do I use in the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do URL re-writing in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-do-url-re-writing-in-php)

Comment: Sorry, that did not work. I just get 500 or 404 errors when I try those, including the advice in the link.

Comment: you are passing those variables `tab=go&page=stuff` to index.php i assume.

Comment: @Warwick: Can you show your attempted rules in question and also tell what URL is causing 500?

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar, sorry, yes, I am passing to index.php – have edited my original post.

Comment: @anubhava, I have attempted so many different rules, I don't know where to start! I have just been copying and pasting from the web. I have no knowledge of rewrite syntax at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?tab=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is correct, except `page=$2`, instead of `$1`. This helps me understand where I was going wrong, as well. I get it now! Thanks!

Comment: Ah you're right, it was a typo, should have been `page=$2`