# Php use url as variable execute on root

Tags: php, api

Suppose I have an api: api.example.com, this code actually gets the contents of api.example.com/Browser/API/ping.php (this is a simple ping script). Now I want to be able to do something like api.example.com/ping/*site_to_ping* (keep in mind, the folder "ping" doesn't exist, neither do I have a folder for every existing site). This would then execute the following: `file_get_contents("api.example.com/Browser/ping?*site_to_ping*");`
Is this possible?

Comment: yes it's possible url rewriting. or routes if you are using frameworks like codeigniter/laravel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-do-url-re-writing-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending an HTTP POST request using [`file_get_contents`](http://fr.php.net/file_get_contents) is not that hard, actually : as you guessed, you have to use the `$site_to_ping` parameter.

There's an example given in the PHP manual, at this page : [HTTP context options][2] *(quoting)* :

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $site_to_ping_name
    )
);

$site_to_ping = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('api.example.com/Browser/ping', false, $site_to_ping);
```

Basically, you have to create a stream, with the right options *(there is a full list on that page)*, and use it as the third parameter to `file_get_contents` -- nothing more ;-)

As a sidenote : generally speaking, to send HTTP POST requests, we tend to use curl, which provides a lot of options an all -- but streams are one of the nice things of PHP that nobody knows about... too bad...

Comment: @FlorianDeBosscher did it work !, make it as answred