# htaccess querystring based urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo

Suppose my website is www.example.com

Earlier the urls of my website was like this **www.example.com/php/bookdetails.php?bid=33**

Last week i changed the urls of my site to this  **www.example.com/bookdetails/33**

and wrote an htacces like this

```
RewriteRule ^bookdetails/(.*)$ php/bookSearchResult.php?bid=$1
```

The problem is that there are some external site using my earlier URL structure (**www.example.com/php/bookdetails.php?bid=33**) and what i want is to redirect it to my new URL structure (**www.example.com/bookdetails/33**).

I know it can be possible in htaccess, but i have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule ^php/bookdetails\.php\?bid=(\d+)$ bookdetails/$1 [L,R=301]`

A PCRE to match the old format, capturing the number, the new URL with the reference to the captured number, Last rule, Redirect with HTTP status 301 (moved permanently)

(*Tested it for syntax, but not to ensure that it works exactly*. I'm fairly sure that if this isn't it, it should be close.)

Make sure this rule is before the other you mentioned rewriting to the proper php URL, or you'll get a 500 for an infinitely looping rewrite.

The [Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html) and the [Advanced Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide_advanced.html) are invaluable resources for examples.

**EDIT:**

BTW, this is a duplicate of [.htaccess and seo friendly urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836917/htaccess-and-seo-friendly-urls), and probably several others, for additional ideas. (I should have looked for a dup first.)