# URL generated page SEO question

Tags: php, url

I have a website and I want to change some pages from static .php pages to pages that load content via MySQL.

Because, the pages are different I'll get the page name through the URL.

So, what I basicaly want is to replace:

```
www.website.com/abcd.php
```

With

```
www.website.com/page.php?id="abcd"
```

And I was wondering if Gooogle and other search engine will index all the pages `page.php?id="abcd"` , `page.php?id="asdfg` etc... or will they only index the page.php page with no content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google will try to index all pages it founds unless it find a HTTP status different than 2XX or 3XX. I recommend you leave the pages as static to add keyword density.

In fact

```
http://www.example.com/this-super-item/123123
```

will be more relevant than

```
http://www.example.com/item.php?id=123123
```

to prevent crawlers to index crap or undesired content I recommend you to throw a HTTP 404 status in case the url make no sense. For example

```
http://www.example.com/item.php?id=
```

where the id is empty.

regarding pretty urls check my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:31039%20rewrite) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836917/htaccess-and-seo-friendly-urls/836958#836958) in particular

saludos

Comment: It seems pretty hard to replace php?id=12123 with /123123 so I'll stick with the id solution. And, how can I throw a 404 status with php? Should I redirect the user to the 404.shtml page or what?

Comment: to throw a 404 status with php use: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

Answer (score 3):

They will index anything they can crawl, including pages with "?id=41984".